# how to hide redundant (auto devops kubernetes CI/CD) button in gitlab project page

Tags: gitlab

I'll never use this functions, so how to hide them.

## GitLab Community Edition 10.8.2

[image: buttons]

Comment: it's almost 6 years later now and I ask myself the same question now. Have you found a way to hide these functions?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

**You can't**

Gitlab doesn't provide an option to hide these at the moment.

However you could technically use a browser plugin which injects custom CSS to hide it. (for example [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-style-script/))